# Case expression with two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a case statement in SQL Server 2008 that uses the following syntax

```
case
    when [Phone1] = 'Cell' then [CellNumber]
    when [Phone1] = 'Home' then [HomeNumber]
    when [Phone1] = 'Work' then [WorkNumber]
    when [Phone2] = 'Cell' then [CellNumber2]
    when [Phone2] = 'Home' then [HomeNumber2]
    when [Phone2] = 'Work' then [WorkNumber2]
    else [CellNumber]
end as [PrimaryPhone]
```

The statement itself runs fine, however it doesn't ever use my else statement. If I put else 'TextExample', it will put that in my results but I cannot get it to output Column1 in the result of a null value.

I have also tried the following to no avail.

```
case 
    when [ColumnX] = 'Value1' then [Column1] 
    when [ColumnX] = 'Value2' then [Column2]
    when [ColumnX] = 'Value3' then [Column3]
    when [ColumnY] = 'Value1' then [Column4]
    when [ColumnY] = 'Value2' then [Column5]
    when [ColumnY] = 'Value3' then [Column6]
    when [Column X] is null and [Column Y]is null then [Column1]
    else [Column1]
end as [ColumnName]
```

Here is an example of my 
[Output from query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLYUi.png)

I am expecting ColumnName to always be filled in with Column 1-6, however the else is always ignored, I am assuming because one of the above when statements in the searched case is true, but it isn't putting the value there in turn. It is giving me a null value even though one of the above when's was true, and the result should not(I don't think at least) be a null value.

I have edited my first example to have column names/plain english.

Comment: Are you sure [Column1] is not null when none of the `when` conditions are true?

Comment: Your code really looks fine, so I suspect the error lies somewhere else. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @trincot for the examples I am having the issue with, Column1 does have a value

Comment: Please edit your question and add some example data, the result you get for that data, and what you expected as output for it.

Comment: Case expression, not case statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
coalesce(case
    when [ColumnX] = 'Value1' then [Column1]
    when [ColumnX] = 'Value2' then [Column2]
    when [ColumnX] = 'Value3' then [Column3]
    when [ColumnY] = 'Value1' then [Column4]
    when [ColumnY] = 'Value2' then [Column5]
    when [ColumnY] = 'Value3' then [Column6]
end, [Column1]) as [ColumnName]
```

The reason you need the `coalesce()` is that even though you're selecting one of the six columns based on the values in two other columns you haven't also guaranteed that the corresponding value is not null. The `coalesce()` says that where the computed value is missing, use `Column1` by default. You could extend that this way if necessary:

```
coalesce(
...
end, [Column1], [Column2], [Column3] ...) as [ColumnName]
```

Your first attempt looks like it should have worked as long as the flagged value  doesn't turn out to be null. It seems likely that this wasn't supposed to happen so perhaps that's really where the problem lies.

Comment: this is looking very promising, can you explain why this works and the case by itself wouldn't?

Comment: @Shark50521 It sounds like the `case` is evaluating to null because it found a match but the corresponding value in `column[1-6]` was missing.

Comment: Actually I answered before your edit and I can't make a lot of sense of that now that I read it. And we can't determine much from the sample days without knowing the special literal values in the expression.

Comment: @Shark50521 It would be incredibly helpful if you could just explain in plain English what you're looking to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry couldn't get back to it before this. I edited my first example above so it is in more plain english. Basically Phone1 and Phone2 hold values. Sometimes they are null or will have 3 values in them. When it is one of the 3 values I want the corresponding value, but when it is null I just want it to write out the cell phone column as seen above.

Comment: @Shark50521 So I think it turns out that I was right after all. You image was a little misleading because the X/Y values just looked like other phone numbers.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, neglected to say  I was doing another transformation above that where I change the label into the actual phone # in my output results. Coalesce is working for me so I'm going to mark this as accepted, now its just a matter of deciding where I put nulls or if I need them. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the null comparisons to the beginning of the `CASE` statement.  Your second approach is more suited.  You should do (as makes sense) a check for `[Column X] IS NULL`, then `[Column Y] IS NULL`, then both (with an `AND` clause).

Comment: this worked for part of it, but not others, I appreciate the direction to head towards though. I think this plus coalesce is going to get me there.